# Not able to split the Ajax response in separate Div

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to split the Ajax response in two separate Div. I am getting the response in a single Div. Please see the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.post("check.php", {
      job: exactdatainner,
      attrb: getattr
    },
    function(data, status) {
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);

      var obj = data.split('||');
      $(".job").html(obj[0]);
      $(".attribute").html(obj[1]);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="job"></div>
<div class="attribute"></div>



<?php
    $job = $_POST['job'];
    $attrb = $_POST['attrb'];
    echo $job;
    echo $attrb;
    ?>
```

I am getting the result but all the result printing inside first div only Here is the PHP code

Comment: Please post the PHP code that generates the response.

Comment: Are there 2 or more items in the array generated by splitting the reponse on double pipe?

Comment: Edited with PHP code

Comment: What is the data response ?  Sounds like there is no '||' in the response.

Comment: You probably would be better off encoding a JSON and then using a dataType of json in the request.  You'll have an object and you won't have use some arbitrary delimeter for parsing.  Seems a little strange ?  You are just posting to a page and then returning the same data back to the AJAX call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `echo` out the PHP logic *where* you want it to appear on the page:

```
<?php
$job = $_POST['job'];
$attrb = $_POST['attrb'];
?>

<div class="job"><?php echo $job; ?></div>
<div class="attribute"><?php echo $attrb; ?></div>
```

Or alternatively you can `echo` out the HTML components as well:

```
<?php
$job = $_POST['job'];
$attrb = $_POST['attrb'];
echo "<div class='job'>$job</div>";
echo "<div class='attribute'>$attrb</div>";
?>
```

Comment: It's not working : the php code is on another page and I want it on same page where ajax was written